# String.Replace with double spaces fails

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2012

I am trying to replace all double spaces with single spaces.

However, this does not work in the following case:

```
Dim s As String = "SECTIONSHOMESEARCHSKIP TO CONTENTSKIP TO NAVIGATIONVIEW MOBILE VERSION   SETTINGS  Loading...    MAGAZINE    JUNE 11, 2014  Photo    Credit Jude Edginton for The New York Times  Continue reading the main storyContinue reading the main story  Talk  Intervie..."

s = s.Replace("  ", " ")

Debug.Assert(InStr(s, "  ", CompareMethod.Binary) = 0)'Assertion occurs
```

Does anybody see what might be going wrong here?

Thank you!

Comment: some of the gaps are in fact 3 spaces, so 3-2+1 = 2.  just run the Replace twice.  the first time thru, the length goes from 259 to 247 so it is working. or `Do While s.Contains("  ")//replace//End Loop`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to loop, because something with more than 2 spaces won't be done in the first iteration

```
do
  s = s.Replace("  ", " ")
loop until while InStr(s, "  ", CompareMethod.Binary)=0
```

Comment: Well, I don't like it, but it is the fastest

Answer (score 2):

You have spaces with length > 2, that's why it doesn't work.

You could use `String.Split` with `StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries` + `String.Join`:

```
s = String.Join(" ", s.Split({" "c}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries))
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use Regex.Replace

```
Dim s As String = "SECTIONSHOMESEARCHSKIP TO CONTENTSKIP TO NAVIGATIONVIEW MOBILE VERSION   SETTINGS  Loading...    MAGAZINE    JUNE 11, 2014  Photo    Credit Jude Edginton for The New York Times  Continue reading the main storyContinue reading the main story  Talk  Intervie..."
Dim r = Regex.Replace(s, "[ ]{2,}", " "c)
Console.WriteLine(r)

=> SECTIONSHOMESEARCHSKIP TO CONTENTSKIP TO NAVIGATIONVIEW MOBILE VERSION SETTINGS Loading... MAGAZINE JUNE 11, 2014 Photo Credit Jude Edginton for The New York Times Continue reading the main storyContinue reading the main story Talk Intervie...
```

The Regex.Replace  `"[ ]{2,}", " "c` means, find any sequence of TWO or MORE spaces and replace it with one single SPACE character.

**EDIT**
I was curious to know what is the difference in performance between Regex and the solution based on string.Join/Split proposed by Tim Schmelter. It seems that notwithstanding all the work required to split the line, build an array and then rejoin everything, the proposed approach of Tim is faster.

```
Dim sw = new Stopwatch()
sw.Start()
for i = 0 to 1000000
Dim r = Regex.Replace(s, "[ ]{2,}", " "c)
Next
sw.Stop
Console.WriteLine("Regex:" & sw.ElapsedMilliseconds)

sw = new Stopwatch()
sw.Start()
for i = 0 to 1000000
    s = String.Join(" ", s.Split({" "c}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries))
Next
sw.Stop
Console.WriteLine("Split/Join: " & sw.ElapsedMilliseconds)
```

Outputs on my PC

```
Regex: 6265 
Split/Join: 3745
```